# Creating and modifying a script library USING app script

Tags: google-apps-script

So! I have a script that spits out forms and linked spreadsheets. I want the script to then add a function to the linked spreadsheet that fires on form submit.

How can app script create a script project bound to the new spreadsheet? That is -- if it were a person doing it, they'd do "Extensions -> App Script" but I want to accomplish this programatically...

Any ideas? I'd hate to think this isn't possible.

Comment: [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)